# Generic term for Block and Allow

Tags: generic-term

Is there a generic term for "block" and "allow"?

Use case: I have a list that can either be a block list or an allow list. I'm looking for a term that "covers" both allow and block.

Comment: Do not write answers in comments. If you have an answer, write an answer in the "Your answer" box.

Comment: Do you have more specific context? It's not clear from your question why "list" itself wouldn't suffice.

Comment: Our Help Center says that picking names for things in computer programming is off topic here.

Comment: @tchrist thanks, I was not aware of that. But nonetheless - are you sure this is strictly a computer programming issue? Are there no block/allow lists in other fields that can benefit from this question?

Answer (score 3):

These are instances of **permissions**.

The concept of [file system permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions) is well established in computing, giving different rights to read, write, modify, etc, files. Wikipedia also has an article about [application permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_permissions), which are permissions given or denied to applications (e.g. phone apps): "Permissions are a means of controlling and regulating access to specific system- and device-level functions by software."

Answer (score 1):

I've just discovered that apparently [some people don't like the perceived racist overtones](https://www.selfdefined.app/definitions/blacklist-whitelist/) of...

[**black/whitelist**](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/whitelist)
*a cybersecurity strategy that **rejects/accepts** a list of email addresses, IP addresses, domain names or applications, while **accepting/rejecting** all others*
[highlighting added by me to combine the two complementary definitions]

...but I think unless you're already avoiding ***blackboard, whiteboard,...*** you can probably just ignore the snowflakes.

Comment: It's not a 'snowflake' thing, it's pretty universal now -- since the BLM movement started. It's also the reason 'master' in git is now called 'main' (by default, in GitHub).

Comment: If I was the last person left on earth who thinks such attitudes are ridiculous, I'd still say everyone else was "snowflakes". And while George Floyd's death was obviously regrettable, I think it's far *more* regrettable that this propelled BLM into the limelight and increased their access to funding and influence. That's a *seriously* nasty organization, imho.